# Dynamic sculpting doesn't work

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I'm quite a beginner, and I was following a tutorial to learn how to use dynamic sculpting when, all of the sudden, it stopped working (I tested with the snake hook tool thingy, and it isn't incrementing more mesh.). The last thing I remember doing that was different was using the simplify tool to remove artifacts of me being a noob at this. :P

Is there any kind of action that after being done doesn't allow going back to dynamic?

I did a quick search and found nothing; sorry if this is asked a lot. :/

Comment: If you exit sculpt mode and re-enter it, dyntopo will be disabled and you must re-enable it (`Ctrl+D`).

Comment: erm, i know that, i always enable it, but thanks to that i noticed that i had in colapse edges mode (wich looked alot like not have dyno at all) so i changed to subdivide edges and its done ty :) should i delete the post?

Comment: Ah, okay. Instead of deleting it, feel free to add your own answer by using the answer button so it's easier for other people to find :)